# django-heroku and psycopg2 installed but shows "import django_heroku ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'"

Tags: django, heroku

Firstly i installed psycopg2 then django_heroku.

**setting.py**

```
import django_heroku
import os
---
---
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Here are my requirements which are installed in virtual environments.

**requirements.txt**

```
asgiref==3.2.7
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.5
django-contrib-comments==1.9.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.23.0
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

After pushing in heroku master it shows.

**Activity Log**

```
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_e4e9cada1e303d2ab0fdd618bffc8af4/covid19/covid19/settings.py", line 13, in <module>
           import django_heroku
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
 !     Error while running '$ python covid19/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Other Problem arrives here that, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'covid19.wsgi'". 
But I used it in my Procfile.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn covid19.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem after understanding the root directory. 
My project was not in root directory.

When i created the project by the command

```
django-admin startproject projectname
```

It creates two folder projectname -> projectname

But, if we command such that.

```
django-admin startproject projectname .
```

It creates only one folder folder projectname where manage.py stays.

And it is the root directory. So, i copied all apps and other files and folder and pasted in the root folder, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your procfile to :
`web: gunicorn --chdir covid19 covid19.wsgi`

If your root directory doesn't match the direct path you provided, the `--chdir` will tell it to match based on the directory listed. So basically if your `wsgi.py` is in your root directory, your original procfile will work, but if your root directory is in the parent folder, it will not recognize your wsgi because it is in a different location then the root directory (the most common seemingly being the root directory being a level higher then expected, which the suggested procfile will resolve)